# I can't see the content of the mounted disk in the Docker volume

Tags: debian, docker

In `docker-compose.yaml` I have mounted directory `/var/www/` (for clarity I will name this directory as `/foo/bar/`) as volume `/var/www/` in my Docker container (to have Apache document root directory from host available in Docker container).

`docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
....
    volumes:
      - /foo/bar/:/var/www/
...
```

It worked very well until now. Now I had to enlarge space for websites and mounted new disk partition into `/foo/bar/hdd2` in host. New partition is mounted as `/foo/bar/hdd2`

```
cat /proc/mounts | grep hdd2
/dev/vdb1 /foo/bar/hdd2 ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

But I do not see content of `/foo/bar/hdd2` in Docker container, the directory `/var/www` is empty even though there are files/directories in the directory in host environment.

Docker container's `/var/www/hdd2` content:

```
root@http:/var/www/hdd2# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 May 27 19:03 .
drwxrwxr-x 23 www-data www-data 4096 May 27 19:03 ..
```

Is there any reason why I can't see the content of the directory linked to the new disk partition in the Docker container's volume directory?